# How To Get Running Subtotal with Group By in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get a running sub-total of amounts for a group in SQL 2014?

I have a table with transaction amounts. I need to summarize to get a row for each project and quarter for which there is data, and need a running subtotal within each project. The running total would need to reset to zero for each new project.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT [ProjectId]
    , SUM( ActualAmount) AS PeriodAmount
    , SUM( ActualAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY ProjectId,YearQuarter) 
        AS FairMarketValue

    FROM GLSnapshot 
    GROUP BY [ProjectId] , [YearQuarter]
```

I currently get this error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3

```
Column 'GLSnapshot.ActualAmount' is invalid in the 
select list because it is not contained in either an 
aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Sample Data: Assuming I have the following data for table GLSnapshot:

```
ProjectId, YearQuarter, ActualAmount
'A', '2015Q1' , 9000.00
'A', '2015Q1' ,  100.00
'A', '2015Q2' ,   50.00
'A', '2015Q3' ,   50.00
'A', '2015Q3' ,  200.00
'B', '2015Q1' ,80000.00
```

I should get the following result for

```
ProjectId, YearQuarter, PeriodAmount, FairMarketValue (Running Subtotal): 
'A', '2015Q1' , 9100.00 ,  9100.00
'A', '2015Q2' ,   50.00 ,  9150.00
'A', '2015Q3' ,  250.00 ,  9400.00
'B', '2015Q1' ,80000.00 , 80000.00
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include sample data along with the expected result set.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: does it work if you comment out your fairMarketValue calc?  Also, I think you'll have to split your `yearQuarter` value into separate `Year` and `Quarter` fields.

Comment: @Beth --Well, it will run if I comment out the line:
, SUM( ActualAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY ProjectId,YearQuarter) AS FairMarketValue
But of course, I get no running total. Also, I don't thing we need to split out Year and Quarter. We don't need a separate subtotal by year. If it helps, you can think of YearQuarter as a unique period identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLAP functions are calculated **after** aggregation, you can't use `ActualAmount`, must be `SUM( ActualAmount)`. And there's no need to order by `ProjectId` because it's already in `PARTITION BY`. Finally use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` otherwise it defaults to `RANGE UNBOUNDED  PRECEDING` which is more expensive and might not return the expected result:

```
SELECT [ProjectId]
    , [YearQuarter]
    , SUM( ActualAmount) AS PeriodAmount
    , SUM( SUM( ActualAmount))
      OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId
            ORDER BY YearQuarter
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS FairMarketValue

    FROM GLSnapshot 
    GROUP BY [ProjectId] , [YearQuarter]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rows unbounded preceding which will give running total

```
;with cte as (
select ProjectID, YearQuarter, ActualAmount
from GLSnapshot
) , cte2 as (
select ProjectID, YearQuarter, sum(ActualAmount) SumActualAmount  from cte Group by ProjectID, YearQuarter
) Select *, sum(SumActualAmount) over(partition by projectid order by projectid, yearquarter rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal from cte2
```

Comment: I get the same error as above: Column 'GLSnapshot.ActualAmount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Changed the query to correct based on your input set

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #GLSnapshot (ProjectId VARCHAR(5), YearQuarter VARCHAR(6), ActualAmount NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #GLSnapshot

SELECT 'A', '2015Q1' , 9000.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '2015Q1' ,  100.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '2015Q2' ,   50.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '2015Q3' ,   50.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '2015Q3' ,  200.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', '2015Q1' ,80000.00



;WITH T
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ProjectId ORDER by YearQuarter) RN,
    ProjectId,YearQuarter,sum(ActualAmount) PeriodAmount
    FROM #GLSnapshot
    GROUP BY ProjectId,YearQuarter
)
SELECT T1.ProjectId,T1.YearQuarter,T1.PeriodAmount, SUM(T2.PeriodAmount) FairMarketValue 
FROM T T1
INNER JOIN T T2 ON T1.ProjectId = T2.ProjectId and T1.RN >= T2.RN
GROUP BY T1.ProjectId,T1.YearQuarter,T1.PeriodAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query using ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

```
;with cte as (
select ProjectID, YearQuarter, ActualAmount
 from GLSnapshot
) , cte2 as (
select ProjectID, YearQuarter, sum(ActualAmount) SumActualAmount  from cte Group by ProjectID, YearQuarter
) Select *, sum(SumActualAmount) over(partition by projectid order by projectid, yearquarter rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal from cte2
```